# Converting string to illegal/unsupported expression in Mathematica.

Tags: string, wolfram-mathematica, expression, multidimensional-array, taylor-series

I need to input a variable, say `var`, into Mathematica function Series[ ] like this: `Series[A^2+B^2+C^2, var]`. Series[ ] has the following syntax:

> Series[f, {x, x_0, n}] generates a power series expansion for f about the point x=x_0 to order n.
>   Series[f, {x, x_0, n}, {y, y_0, m}, ...] successively finds series expansions with respect to x, then y, etc.

Because I am not always computing Series[ ] in one dimension (i.e., `B` and `C` are not always variables at each iteration), `var` must be properly formatted to fit the dimension demands. The caveat is that Mathematica likes lists, so any table degenerated will have a set of outer `{}`.

Suppose my previous code generates the following two sets of sets:

> table[1]= {{A, 0, n}};
>   table[2]= {{A, 0, n}, {B, 0, m}}; .

My best idea is to use string manipulation (for i= 2):

> string = ToString[table[i]]; .
>   str = StringReplacePart[string, {" ", " "}, {{1}, {StringLength[string], StringLength[string]}}]

The next step is to convert `str` to an expression like `var` and do `Series[A^2 + B^2 + C^2, var]` by doing `var= ToExpression[str]`, but this returns the following error:

> ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before "{A, 0, n}, {B, 0, m}".
>   $Failed

Help convert `str` to expression propertly or suggest another way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you have

```
table[2] = {{A, 0, n}, {B, 0, m}};
```

and are trying to obtain from that

```
Series[f[A,B],{A,0,n},{B,0,m}]
```

This may be done using `Sequence`, like so (I will use `series` instead of `Series` to keep it unevaluated so you can see what is happening):

```
series[f[A, B], Sequence @@ table[2]]
(*
-> series[f[A,B],{A,0,n},{B,0,m}]
*)
```

So for instance

```
table[3] = {{A, 0, 2}, {B, 0, 2}};
Series[f[A, B], Sequence @@ table[3]]
```

gives the right series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/First.html) or [`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Last.html) or more generally, [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) to get the `List` you want. For e.g.,

```
var = {{x, 0, 3}, {x, 0, 5}};
Series[1/(1 + x), var[[1]]]

Out[1]= 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + O[x]^4

Series[1/(1 + x), var[[2]]]

Out[2]= 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5 + O[x]^6
```

---

#### EDIT:

For multiple variables, you can use a [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) (`##`) along with [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (`@@`) like so:

```
Series[Sin[u + w], ##] & @@ {{u, 0, 3}, {w, 0, 3}}
```

Comment: Yes this does work for picking only one set of parameters out of the list. But what if I want to do `Series[1/(1 + x+y), {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 5}]`? I see an iterative approach in mind that I am working on right now.

Comment: Iterative approach (notice that from a mathematical stand point there is no difference between taking a Taylor approximation using x then y or y then x):



Suppose that during your iteration you know that you will be using table[2], then do the following:
> S= Normal[Series[A^2+B^2+C^2, tables[2][[1]]]]; (* Normal[ ] abandons O(n) notation*)  For[k = 2, k <= Length[table[2]], k++,  
>  S = Normal[Series[S, table[2][[k]];  
>  ];  

So this is equivalent to `S= Normal[Series[A^2+B^2+C^2, tables[2][[1]], tables[2][[2]]]];`.